# Telerik Reports bug with Azure

Tags: c#, azure, telerik, telerik-reporting

I have strange bug with Telerik Reporting. I wanted to show one report in my app so I added Telerik's ReoirtViever. When I'm opening it I'm getting ecxeption:

```
Not running in a hosted service or the Development Fabric.
```

It is strange because this exception is associated with Windows Azure and I'm not using it right now. I have Windows Azure Project in my solution, but to test reports I wanted to use IIS. What can be wrong here?

EDIT: I even deleted my all azure projects from solution but it haven't helped. Also I created new app in onter solution to test if I add this report in a good way. And it's working there correctly, but I have to run it in my old solution.

Comment: Does your web application has webrole.cs?

Comment: Can you check in your code or web.config for anything that would be required for the code to run in Windows Azure or compute emulator. I would look for Windows Azure Diagnostics or RoleEnvironment.